# Add missing periods to newlines in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to write a regex in Python that does the following

Convert all sentences that end with `[alphanumeric]\n` and replace it with "."

So for example

```
I went there
I also went there.
It is


That-
I too went there!
It went there?
It is 3
```

so let's say we have

Should be converted to

```
I went there.
I also went there.
It is.


That-
I too went there!
It went there?
It is 3.
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: The input string is

```
s = "I went there\nI also went there.\nIt is\n\nThat-\nI too went there!\nIt went there?\nIt is 3"
```

Also, "?" should not be appended with a "."

EDIT2: I modified the example so it contains a double `\n` and a sentence ending with `-`. So "-" should not be appended with a "."

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?<![!.,])\n', '.\n', s)`

Comment: You start out by saying you only want to leave line-ending exclamation points, commas, and periods alone (adding a period to everything else); but then in your example, you leave a line-ending question mark alone.

Comment: See my edit. I meant that the string `s` is one long sentence with "\n"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
s = 'I went there'

if s[-1] not in ['!', ',', '.', '\n']:
    s += '.'
```

**Edit:**

With your new input, the following should work:

```
new_string = ''.join('{}.\n'.format(item) if (item and item[-1] not in '!?.,-') else '{}\n'.format(item) for item in s.split('\n'))
```

If you do not want `\n` at the end of `new_string`, you can remove it:

```
new_string = new_string.rstrip('\n')
```

**Output:**

```
>>> s = "I went there\nI also went there.\nIt is\n\nThat-\nI too went there!\nIt went there?\nIt is 3"
>>> new_string = ''.join('{}.\n'.format(item) if (item and item[-1] not in '!?.,-') else '{}\n'.format(item) for item in s.split('\n'))
>>>
>>> print(new_string)
I went there.
I also went there.
It is.

That-
I too went there!
It went there?
It is 3.
```

Comment: My apologies. I meant that I'm looking at one long string `s` with "\n"'s , as opposed to working with multiple separate lines. See the EDIT

Comment: that's always smart to propose non-regex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `re.sub()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
s = "I went there\nI also went there.\nIt is\n\nThat-\nI too went there!\nIt went there?\nIt is 3"
s = re.sub(r'(?<=[^,.!?-\s])(\n|$)', r'.\1', s, re.M)
print(s)
```

The output:

```
I went there.
I also went there.
It is.

That-
I too went there!
It went there?
It is 3.
```

---

`(\n|$)` - matches a linebreak(new line) or the end of the string

`(?<=[^,.!?-\s])` - ensures that there's no specific characters before the above mentioned match

`\1` - refers to the first capturing group which is `(\n|$)`

Comment: Thats close, but not quite what I wanted. I made edits explained in "EDIT2" that explains what I was looking for

Comment: @user5739619, I didn't expect you to change the initial condition, but, anyway, check my update